# Set a specific date and year in a MS CRM date time field in the onchange event

Tags: javascript, date, dynamics-crm-2011

I have two date time fields.
In the first field, if the date is set, then in the second date time field, the date should be automatically populated
with this format.

**For example**:

**Start date**: 1: 09/30/2016

**End date 2**: 09/29/2017.

**Following is my code:**

```
function SetOneplusyearminus1date() {
debugger;
var start = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("msdyn_startdate").getValue();
if (start != null)
{
    var endYear = start.setYear(start.getFullYear() + 1);
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("msdyn_enddate").setValue(endYear);
}}
```

I have set the year but unable to set the Date.
So please help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
function SetOneplusyearminus1date() {
   debugger;
   var start = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("msdyn_startdate").getValue();
   if (start != null) {
       start.setDate(start.getDate() - 1);
       start.setYear(start.getFullYear() + 1);
       Xrm.Page.getAttribute("msdyn_enddate").setValue(start);
   }
}
```